# Getting gibberish when sending push notification in Hebrew from java server to android phone using GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, hebrew, google-cloud-messaging

I am using app engine to send push notification in Hebrew to smartphone using Google Cloud Messaging, but when i receive the message on phone the text is ??????? instead of Hebrew.

Here the code for preparing Post message to phone using JSON object:

```
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                JSONArray registrationsIDList = new JSONArray();

                Query newsQuery = new Query("Devices");
                List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(newsQuery).asList(
                        FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
                if(results!=null)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<results.size();j++)
                    {
                        Entity entity=results.get(j);
                        if(entity!=null)
                        {
                            String ID=(String) entity.getProperty("Registration ID");
                            if(ID!=null)
                            {
                                registrationsIDList.put(ID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                LinkedHashMap data = new LinkedHashMap();
                data.put("Subject",subjects.get(i).getSubject());
                data.put("Writer", subjects.get(i).getWriter());
                data.put("SubjectDate", subjects.get(i).getLastCommentDateTime());
                data.put("SubjectLink", subjects.get(i).getSubjectLink());

                try {
                    obj.put("registration_ids", registrationsIDList);
                    obj.put("data", data);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



                //Sending message to GCM for devices


                try 
                {
                    URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json ; charset=utf-8");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=*************************************");

                    OutputStream writer = connection.getOutputStream();
                    Entity tmp=new Entity("JSON");
                    tmp.setProperty("Message", obj.toString());
                    datastore.put(tmp);
                    writer.write(obj.toString().getBytes());
                    writer.close();

                    Entity device=new Entity("Messages Results");
                    device.setProperty("Response Code", connection.getResponseCode());
                    device.setProperty("Response Message", connection.getResponseMessage());
                    datastore.put(device);
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    } else {
                        // Server returned HTTP error code.
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    // ...
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // ...
                }
```

Before sending the message, i checked that JSON object holds proper Hebrew text.

Here the code for receiving the message on phone:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
    String str = arg1.getExtras().getString("Subject");
    Log.d("GCM", str);
    String str1 =arg1.getExtras().getString("Writer");
    Log.d("GCM", str1);
    String str2 =arg1.getExtras().getString("SubjectDate");
    Log.d("GCM", str2);
    String str3 =arg1.getExtras().getString("SubjectLink");
    Log.d("GCM", str3);
}
```

Now the text is ????????????????? instead of Hebrew.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code helped me to understand how to read the Json response from the server when push notification received on client side. Thank you so much Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Unicode: `.toString.getBytes("UTF8")`

Comment: Alex I have the same exact issue!! Looking for hours..Can you post a working example?Thanks!